# How to keep list last item above bottomsheeet

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, bottom-sheet

I am building a music player. I am working with `bottomsheet`. Its working fine and it has its peek height, But it covers the RecyclerView last item. 
How can I set `recyclerView` above `BottomSheet` view. 
Please help me.

Here is my MainActivity XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/tab_root"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            />

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/orange"
            app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/colorAccent"
            app:tabIndicatorHeight="3dp"
            app:tabMode="fixed"
            app:tabTextColor="@color/white" />
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

    <!-- View useed to load other fragments so that my Bottomsheet can be seen above other fragments -->
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        />
    <!-- BottomSheet layout-->
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/framelayouts"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:elevation="8dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        app:layout_behavior="android.support.design.widget.BottomSheetBehavior">

        <include layout="@layout/layout_player_bottomsheet" />
    </FrameLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Please suggest what to do.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add this two properties in your recyclerView.

```
android:clipToPadding="false"
android:paddingBottom="60dp"
```

Comment: its working but sometimes it stuck and do not behave accordingly.. why ?

Comment: what's the problem are you facing exactly?

Comment: list is now coming over bottomsheet but when i change the fragment and come again on it, it behave same as previoulsy. last item goes behind the bottomsheet.

Comment: Check your recyclerview row and bottom sheet view. If recyclerview row root layout is match_parent it change to wrap_content.